# Linking to bootstrap css file from .NET core project

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, asp.net-core

I have a project that I am building with .NET Core 6. I have installed a bootstrap package via Libman, stored under "lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css". I am having some problems linking to this file from the '_layout.cshtml' file in my 'Views/Shared' folder. I wondered if anyone knows of the correct way to hyperlink.

Code of _layout.cshtml is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            <title>SportsStore</title>
            <link href="./twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="bg-dark text-white p-2">
                <span class="navbar-brand ml-2">SPORTS STORE</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row m-1 p-1">
                <div id="categories" class="col-3">
                    Put something useful here later
                </div>
                <div class="col-9">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Screenshot of folder structure of my .NET Core project:

[image: screenshot of folder structure]

I would be very grateful for any advice.

Thanks,

Robert

London, UK

Comment: Use _~/lib/...._ instead of _./lib/...._

Comment: Or probably better use just / without point or tilde. Surely using just a point you are telling to search from the current directory meaning something under Views/Shared

Comment: just drag and drop bootstrap.css file to layout head section, I guess it will automatically generate a link for you to the right address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,make sure you've called`app.UseStaticFiles()`in Program.cs.If you haven't modifyed FileProvider ,create a folder named of "wwwroot" and move your static files into it.Also you could try

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "foldername")),
    
});
```

For more details,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Secondly,try with

```
"~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"
```

If you moved the folder into wwwroot folder

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
@Styles.Render("~/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css")
```

(instead of : )

```
<link href="./twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```